# How to Enable Button in list After 7 Days in android

Tags: android

1. there is a button in my List activity . by default its invisible but I wanna make it visible today date to after 7 days how can i do this one

Answer (score -1):

save the initial date and in `onCreate` get this date, add 7 days and make it visible